# Errors when trying to 'Archive' IOS flutter app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

I am new to IOS app development and this is my first time publishing an app (test flight). When archiving the app it gives me two errors.

1. Failed to create provisioning profile.
   There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
2. No profiles for '(mypackagename)' were found
   Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '(myPackageName)'.

It may be useful to note that I cannot use a physical device as I am connecting to a mac using MacInCloud.

I am not sure what other details you need but feel free to ask.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add at least one device to your developer account. You can get the UDID of a device and add it via your Apple developer account web site

Comment: @Paulw11 where in apple developer do I go to add the UDID please.

Comment: "Certificates, identifiers and profiles->devices"

Comment: I have added a device but the problem remains @Paulw11